# Validating email addresses, is it possible?

Tags: cognito-forms

I am wondering why there is no option to have people validate their entered email address by typing it in a second time?

Is this being worked on, or is there a way to achieve it through the advance editor?

Answer (score 1):

Cognito Forms does not directly support this specific type of validation yet, but here is an approach that will work right now:

1. Add two fields, Email1 and Email2
2. Mark both fields as required
3. Make the Default Value for Email2 be the following calculation:

`=Email1 != null and Email2 != null and Email1 != Email2 ? null : Email2`

This will ensure that the value of Email2 must either be blank or match Email1, and since it is also required, it will prevent the user from submitting a form where the email addresses do not match.

In addition, we plan to add support for [Custom Validation Rules](https://trello.com/c/uzs1CcgV) this year, as it will cover this case and hundreds of other more complex validation scenarios, supporting custom validation logic and error messages.  Please vote on this feature and make suggestions, as this helps us prioritize our upcoming features.

Answer (score 0):

You can now add custom validation to any field or section in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).  You can conditionally show error messages based on custom criteria, such as Email != ConfirmEmail.

[image]

Please review our help documentation for more details:
https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/11/building-forms/advanced-validation#custom-errors